Why main function in an interface instead of a class compiles and runs without problem in Java 17?
I always thought that the main method must be inside of a class in Java, but here it is inside of an interface
public interface Main {
  static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println("HelloWorld");
  }
}

and it compiles and runs without problem
$ javac Main.java 
$ java Main
HelloWorld
$ java -version
openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (Alibaba Dragonwell Standard Edition)-17.0.7.0.7+7-GA (build 17.0.8+7)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (Alibaba Dragonwell Standard Edition)-17.0.7.0.7+7-GA (build 17.0.8+7, mixed mode, sharing)

Can it be an interface as well then?

Does this answer your question? can we have a main() in an interface and different implementations for main() in the classes that implement this interface? as well as this

Please state the rule in the Java Language Specification which you think is being violated.

@user207421 why do you think it would improve the question?

This is absolutely fine according to the JLS v17. From section 12.1 - emphasis mine:

The Java Virtual Machine starts execution by invoking the method main of some specified class or interface, passing it a single argument which is an array of strings.

It looks like some of the other text hasn't been updated to include "or interface" everywhere, but it's definitely a deliberate change.
The first version including "or interface" was v9 - the v8 text still just has "some specified class".

But it also works in Java 8. It was never intended to forbid main methods in interfaces, but before Java 8, there was no possibility to declare static methods in interfaces at all. So with Java 8, the possibility to declare static methods in interfaces also introduced the possibility to declare a main method. The specification change provides clarification.

@Holger: Sounds like it's basically a bug that it wasn't changed in the v8 text then.

I don’t think so. This comment from one of the guys in charge nails it: “The question is not ‘should main methods be allowed’, it is ‘should we have explicitly disallowed main methods now that static methods are permissible in interfaces’…”

@Holger: But it means that the JLS v8 doesn't accurately describe the JDK 8 behavior, if I've understood you correctly. A JVM starting execution by invoking the method main of some specified interface does not conform with the JLS v8 claimed behavior, IMO. (To ask differently: do you believe it was a mistake to add "or interface" in v9? Do you believe it would at least have been better to include that in v8 when the behavior changed?) I'm not sure whether I'm missing something here.

That’s a recurring problem. At some point, it was decided that the formal language of the specification should say “class and/or interface” when both are meant, to leave no doubt. But technically, interfaces are classes, just with some special properties. So the developers have a habit of just saying “class” when they mean both and someone has to go through the texts and clean up or it is changed when someone reports a place where just “class” is said but meant to include interfaces. The launcher never cared whether the main class is an interface (it just calls loadClass of a ClassLoader).

@Holger: As a maintainer of the C# spec, the idea that "an interface is a class" feels like a very confusing way of specifying things. It may well make sense at a VM spec level, but IMO less so at a language level. I suspect if you asked 1000 Java developers whether interfaces are classes, 99% of them would say no.

That’s probably the reason why they decided to use the formal language treating classes and interfaces differently in the specification. But, as hinted, the fact that both are classes shows at a lot of places. They’re uniformly loaded through a “class loader” via a method named “load class”, are uniformly reflected by an instance of a class named Class, which you can retrieve for a known interface via InterfaceName.class.

Since this made me curious, I made a test. I patched java.lang.Object to declare a main method, so calling getMethod on an interface could find it even in versions not supporting static methods declared in interfaces. Then, I told the launcher of Java 6 to run an interface as main class. It worked. Which shows that there were never precautions against interfaces as main class. You simply could not declare a static method in an interface.
